# replace string with variable on file

Tags: string, variables, sed, replace

I have files with several lines like:

```
 ) extent size 256 next size 512 lock mode row;
  ) extent size 512 next size 512 lock mode row;
  ) extent size 256 next size 512 lock mode row;
  ) extent size 512 next size 512 lock mode row;
  ) extent size 256 next size 512 lock mode row;
  ) extent size 512 next size 512 lock mode row;
  ) extent size 512000 next size 48 lock mode row;
  ) extent size 512 next size 512 lock mode row;
```

I would like to change all this lines to:

```
) extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row;
```

I can get all with:

```
cat file | grep "extent size"
```

But I don't know how to change variable text

Thanks for any help,

SP

Comment: `grep` can only extract matched lines, it cannot modify them. You can use `sed` as mentioned in the tags, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for resources to get started

Comment: thanks for reply, yes I have used sed on other scripts for replacement with variables, my problem here is how to replace the numbers as they have different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace all digit chunks with some other number on lines that contain `extent size`.

You may use the following `sed` solution:

```
val=16;
sed "/extent size/{s/[0-9]\{1,\}/$val/g}" file > newfile
```

**Details**

- `/extent size/` - finds lines that contain this text
- `{s/[0-9]\{1,\}/$val/g}` - on the found line, replaces one or more digits with the `val` contents (assuming it will be a simple number, no additional processing is required).

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/ADsuSG).

Comment: it works like a charm, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If comfortable with **awk** solution. Try this:-

```
grep "extent size" filename | awk '$4=$7="16"'
```

Explanation

```
grep "extent size" => Grep the line contain words **"extent size"** 
awk '$4=$7="16"'   => change the value of **column 4 and 7** to 16.
```